# Borland vs. MingW/GCC compilation speeds..

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, mingw, turbo-c

I'm a long time Borland users ( since Turbo C ) ( until BC5.2 ).
I've been using MingW/GCC with CodeBlocks for about a year now, mainly
for the extra support esp. native 64bit integers.

Anyway, I have a query regarding compilation speeds.

I have a C (Win32) file which is apx 60,000 lines in length.
On Borland 5.2 this file takes apx 3-5 seconds to compile.
On GCC it takes a bit over 35 seconds.

The GCC command line options I am using are.

-std=c99  -s -O2  (ive also tried -O)

The final exe size is pretty much the same +/- 50kB.

Why the big difference in compilation time ? and is there
a way to speed up GCC to be comparable to BC5.2 ?

Comment: Come on, there has been no reason to use Borland for a decade now. It's not actually a C++ compiler.

Comment: `gcc -O` is the same as `gcc -O1`. To (almost) completely disable optimization use `gcc -O0`.

Comment: Does the execution time of the resulting binary differ between Borland and GCC?

Comment: @Reba: apparently the OP is not interested in C++ anyways

Comment: @larsman The final exe size is pretty much the same +/- 50kB.

Comment: @Don , I've been using MingW/GCC with CodeBlocks for about a year now.

Comment: @AshodApakian: I asked about execution time, not binary size.

Comment: I'm not questioning if GCC is better than Borland or vice-versa.
Just would like to have an insight as to why Borland compiles the same file 10 times faster ( with the same output both for code generated and size )

Comment: yes, that made very little difference (maybe a second or two).

Answer (score 3):

Borland's compilers were designed from inception to be fast, at least according to [marketing](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/images/20841/tc20ad.jpg) and benchmarking published at the time, and widely acknowledged in the industry.  They target a single architecture, the x86 family.

`gcc` was not designed to be fast.  It is designed to:

- target code for multiple architectures, from embedded controllers to supercomputers
- be hosted on multiple architectures
- keep pace with the ever changing C++ language standard

The divergence of the intended use undoubtedly affects its performance.